# Use pointer to a value as a slice

Tags: pointers, go, slice

Is it possible to convert a pointer to certain value to a slice?

For example, I want to read single byte from `io.Reader` into `uint8` variable. `io.Reader.Read` accepts a slice as its argument, so I cannot simply provide it a pointer to my variable as I'd do in C.

I think that creating a slice of length 1, capacity 1 from a pointer is safe operation. Obviously, it should be the same as creating a slice from an array of length 1, which is allowed operation. Is there an easy way to do this with plain variable? Or maybe I do not understand something and there are reasons why this is prohibited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slice is not only a pointer, like an array in C. It also contains the length and capacity of the data, like this:

```
struct {
  ptr *uint8
  len int
  cap int
}
```

So, yes, you will need to create a slice. Simplest way to create a slice of the `var a uint8` would be `[]uint8{a}`

```
a := uint8(42)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", []uint8{a})
```

(But after rereading your question, this is not a solution as all)

But if you wish to create the slice from the variable, pointing to the same space of memory, you could use the `unsafe` package. This is most likely to be discouraged.

```
fmt.Printf("%#v\n", (*[1]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))[:] )
```

Comment: Yes, I wanted to use a slice to provide an access to variable. So it is not possible to do so without resorting to unsafe methods?

Comment: Go doesn't allow conversion between uint8 and [1]uint8 (which sounds pretty safe to me). So, as far as I know, `unsafe` is the only way to do it. And if I am wrong, I am curious about a better solution myself.

Comment: My answer is for the direct question: "Is it possible...", and yes, it is. But in reality, I would also suggest using jnml's solution.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of (over)complicating this trivial task, why not to use the simple solution? I.e. pass .Read a length-1 slice and then assign its zeroth element to your variable.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I just wanted to know whether there is more good-looking solution without defining slice variables.

Comment: Perhaps use [1]uint8 array instead of uint8 variable. Then it will fit io.Reader.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to overcome my case when I want to supply a variable to `io.Reader`. Go standard library is wonderful!

```
import (
    "io"
    "encoding/binary"
)

...

var x uint8
binary.Read(reader, LittleEndian, &x)
```

As a side effect this works for any basic type and even for some non-basic.

Comment: Nice find! The Go developers has surely created a very useful set of packages for us.

Comment: Do you realize you're (indirectly) using pass by `interface{}`,  reflection and type assertions? Is this a competition to find the slowest possible way which avoids the roughly 2 or so CPU instructions probably used for a simple assignment?

Comment: Yes, I do realize that interface indirection is used here. I'm not striving for performance right now, I was looking for idiomatic solution, finding different things along the way. This is what I found, and I just hoped that it could be useful to someone.